# How can I copy the name of the current file to the clipboard in RStudio?

Tags: rstudio

How can I conveniently copy the name of the current file to the clipboard in RStudio?

For example, in Eclipse, I can select the file in the explorer view, f2, ctrl+c.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a simple shortcut for this, but you can get the name of the current file in the source editor using

```
 rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path
```

I don't think RStudio provides any specific clipboard functions, but this works to write it to the Windows clipboard:

```
writeLines(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path, "clipboard")
```

For other platforms the way to write to the clipboard is different.  On my Mac, this works for me:

```
writeLines(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path, pipe("pbcopy"))
```